# Simplest way to read a csv file using php, and then select one specific value

Tags: php, file, csv

Thank you in advance for your time/help.  I'm a newbie learning php, so please keep that in mind.

1st Question
I need a php script that reads a csv file.

2nd Question
How do I echo a specific cell (row and row/column) in that file

I found this script on a similar reply, the script reads the whole file perfectly, but I only want to select a specific cell/value on that csv file. So how do I echo a specific row or a row and column.

```
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("1.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to select several cases, the best way is to make a multi-dimensional array in php.  Otherwise, just throw a few counters into your while loops and done.

```
$row = 1;
$mycsvfile = array(); //define the main array.
if (($handle = fopen("1.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
        $mycsvfile[] = $data; //add the row to the main array.
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

echo $mycsvfile[3][1]; //prints the 4th row, second column.
```

Answer (score 0):

We can create a table and table fields according to the csv header with the below script. Instead of printing the header, I want to create a table with the table fields as the header. The data in each field may be varchar(50)

```
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("1.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
            for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
                echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
            }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```