# How to read the second column in csv file using PHP?

Tags: php, string, algorithm, file, csv

I need to read the second column data only from the csv file using PHP.

My file csv file datas are

```
 CreatedAt  Name  Bookable
    2015     xxx    20:12:12
    2015     xx1    20:12:40     
    2015     xx1    21:12:50
```

Here, I need to  get the name filled only from above csv file . How to do. Please help me.

Comment: Have you done any research before posting this question on SO?

Comment: I refered this link. But its not working for me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066852/simplest-way-to-read-a-csv-file-using-php-and-then-select-one-specific-value

Comment: How does a question showing a complete lack of effort get two upvotes?

Comment: I get the explode idea of adrian cid almaguer..so only I gave the upvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little tired, but this will work

```
<?php

$file = file('1.csv');

for($i = 1; $i < count($file); $i++) {
    echo array_values(array_unique(explode(' ', $file[$i])))[2] . "<br>\n";
}
```

Output:

> xxx
>    xx1
>    xx1