# PHP and CSV formating duplication

Tags: php, html, csv

So i want to output a title of a document and some text after it from my CSV file!..

But i keep getting the format for the title/$line_of_text[0] :

for where i want the un-fomated text still nesting around the text/$line_of_text[3] should be!

```html
<?PHP
    $file_handle = fopen("test.csv", "r");
    while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
        $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
        print "<h2>" . $line_of_text[0] . "</h2></div>\n" . $line_of_text[3] . "<br>";
    }
    fclose($file_handle);
?>
```

So this is how i want it to output :

```html
<h2>Title</h2></div>
The main text
<br>
```

But this is what i get :

```html
<h2>Title</h2></div>
<br><h2>The main text</h2></div>
<br>
```

So obviously im getting a loop that i dont understand!.

Link where i found this code : http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php10p6.html

Comment: What do you want to output exactly in html ?

Comment: <h2>Title</h2></div>
The main text
<br>

Comment: Do it with out loop?

Comment: @rad11 It dont need to be a loop!.. just pick up those 2 things!.. The end :)

Comment: Ok i tried another code and it worked!.. [Solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066852/simplest-way-to-read-a-csv-file-using-php-and-then-select-one-specific-value)